# JDBC - JTDS bug ? For columns of type date and time(x)

Tags: java, jdbc, jtds

When I'm trying to get column type from `ResultSetMetaData`
 with method `getColumnTypeName` for types **`date`** and **`time(x)`** , I'm getting
 **`nvarchar`**. For other types seems it works fine. Is this a bug? With `ResultSet` `getString("TYPE_NAME")` it seems ok. I'm running on `MSSQL2008`

@a_horse_with_no_name

`ResultSetMetaData` I'm getting when executing query. In that case I haven't any tables. Here is the code snippet

```
if (resultType == ResultMappingType.QUERY){ // For Query
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = executeAndValidateQuery(statement, resultName);
    ResultSetMetaData rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
    for( int i = 1 ; i < rsMeta.getColumnCount()+1 ; i ++ ){
        columnInfo.put( rsMeta.getColumnName(i), rsMeta.getColumnTypeName(i));
    }

}else { //For View & Table
    ResultSet rsColumns = meta.getColumns(catalog, schemaPattern, resultName, null);
    while (rsColumns.next()){
        columnInfo.put(rsColumns.getString("COLUMN_NAME"), rsColumns.getString("TYPE_NAME"));
    }
}
....
private ResultSet executeAndValidateQuery(Statement statement, String query) throws KbValidationException{
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        throw new KbValidationException(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. `ResultSet.getString()` is something completely different than `ResultsSetMetaData.getColumnTypeName()`.  Please show us the query you are running and the table definition of your table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have posted code snippet

Comment: And how does the *query* look like that where you get the wrong type name?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

Very Simple `Select * FROM DDD`;
Here are the table columns
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DDD](
 [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [DayId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [MonthId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [YearId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [D1] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [D2] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [D3] [date] NOT NULL,
 [D4] [date] NOT NULL,
 [D5] [time](7) NOT NULL,
 [D6] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DDD] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]`

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm this. It seems that `DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()` also returns the wrong information. You should log a bug with the jTDS driver (it works correctly with the Microsoft driver)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

Yes, but I think it not works only under `MSSQL2008`. It seems ok  under `MSSQL2005`

Comment: This is a known JTDS bug, see http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/679/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known JTDS bug, see [sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/679](http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/679)