# Wrong data type returned for date in jtds.jar

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I have a table on MS SQL Server with a column having data type as date. I am using jtds.jar for JDBC connection with DB.  I am taking  DatabaseMetaData from Connection.  While checking  columns from DatabaseMetaData, I observed that

```
int iType = rsMeta.getInt("DATA_TYPE");
```

returns Column type as `java.sql.Types.VARCHAR` which is a string and not date. but it also returns

```
String tmp = rsMeta.getString("TYPE_NAME");
```

type name as date.

But for Oracle, It returns the date datatype as `java.sql.Types.DATE`.

Why is such a difference?

Comment: why don't you just use `.getTimestamp("DATA_TYPE")`

Comment: As per my knowledge getInt("DATA_TYPE") should return one of types from
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.DATE

Comment: I also found similar link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885459/jdbc-jtds-bug-for-columns-of-type-date-and-timex

Comment: @epoch DATA_TYPE is a column in DatabaseMetaData#getColumns(..) and contains an integer with a value from java.sql.Types.

Comment: check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch

Comment: Simimar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503715/jtds-incorrectly-reports-data-type-info-in-result-set-metadata-for-date-columns/11747222#11747222

Comment: This is a known JTDS bug, see http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/679/.

Comment: @flup, it seems to me, that your comment must be formatted as an answer. I'll +1 it. Also this will cause to remove this question from `unanswered` list.

Comment: A moderator converted it from answer to comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known JTDS bug, see http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/679/.

> The returned datatype for a SQLServer Date type is returned as a
>   varchar with a length of 10. This is wrong, it should return as
>   Sql.Date. int iType = rsMeta.getInt("DATA_TYPE"); String tmp =
>   rsMeta.getString("TYPE_NAME");

Answer (score 2):

This still appears to be an open issue with jTDS 1.3.1. I was able to work around it by querying the SQL Server table catalog directly for the tables I'm working with, and getting a list of date columns for the table:

```
private HashMap<String,Boolean> getDateColumns (String tableName, String schemaName, Connection conn) throws Exception {
    String sql = "SELECT table_name + ',' + column_name" 
                + " FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS " 
                + " WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'" + schemaName + "' "
                + " AND   table_name = N'" + tableName + "' " 
                + " AND data_type IN ('date', 'datetime', 'datetime2')";

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();                        
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    HashMap<String,Boolean> dateCols = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        String tableColKey = rs.getString(1);           
        dateCols.put(tableColKey.toUpperCase(), true );
    }

    rs.close();     
    return dateCols;        
}
```

Once you have this list, you can explicitly check and see if the column is a date type:

```
private ResultSetMetaData getTableMetaData (String tableName, Connection conn) throws Exception {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo." + tableName + " where 1 = 2 ";
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();                        
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    rs.close();

    HashMap<String,Boolean> dateColumns =  getDateColumns (tableName, conn); 

    for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {                

        String key = tableName + "," + rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        int type = -1;
        if (dateColumns.containsKey(key)) {
            type = Types.DATE;
        }
        else {
            type = rsmd.getColumnType(i);
        }

        System.out.println ("... col: " + rsmd.getColumnName(i) + ", driver type name: " + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i) + ", driver type: " + rsmd.getColumnType(i) + ", final data type: " + type);
    }       

    return rsmd;
}
```

So, say I have a sample table with three columns:

```
SAMPLE
------------------
SITE_ID     numeric
START_DATE  date
END_DATE    date
```

This code will print the following values when run with jTDS:

```
... col: SITE_ID, driver type name: numeric, driver type: 2, final data type: 2
... col: START_DATE, driver type name: nvarchar, driver type: 12, final data type: 91
... col: END_DATE, driver type name: nvarchar, driver type: 12, final data type: 91
```

It's not ideal, but it should work for others with a similar problem.