# jTDS incorrectly reports data type info in result set metadata (for DATE columns, reports NVARCHAR)

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, jtds, database-metadata

Currently, the jTDS JDBC driver (1.2.5) against Microsoft SQL Server 2008 appears to incorrectly report the data type for DATE columns as NVARCHAR.

It probably behaves the same for both earlier versions of jTDS and SQL Server (2005, 2000)

- Are there any workarounds for this that don't require switching to a different driver (for example Microsoft's own driver) or patching the jTDS driver?
- Also I would like to avoid having to perform queries against the data dictionary (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view, etc.) to look up the data type information (and possibly cross-referencing against the output of "**exec sp_datatype_info**" in order to retrieve the SQL data types)

A quick perusal of the jTDS outstanding bugs doesn't indicate whether this will be fixed or not.

An answer to this question: [JDBC - JTDS bug ? For columns of type date and time(x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885459/jdbc-jtds-bug-for-columns-of-type-date-and-timex) seems to indicate that this doesn't occur in SQL Server 2005.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 I also have the same issue. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with the condition

`metaData.getColumnType(columnNumber) == 12`

if this condition is satisfied, execute the query

`SELECT System_Type_Id FROM Sys.Columns WHERE Name = [column name] AND Object_Id = (SELECT Object_Id FROM Sys.Tables WHERE Name = [table name])`

for `smalldatetime` it will return `58`

and for `datetime` it will return `61`.

Comment: Interesting find.  Unfortunately the above condition would also evaluate to true if there is a VARCHAR (or NVCHARCHAR) that requires 10 bytes of storage (getPrecision() for a VARCHAR column will return the number of bytes of storage vs getColumnDisplaySize(), which would return the length).