# How to determine database table column size in java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I use JDBC to update a SQL Server table in java.  I update a nvarchar column.  The thing is I don't know how long this column is.  If it has only 30 characters and I update it with 35 characters then it will fail.

Is there a way to find out how long a text column is before I update it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use `getPrecision(int)` method of `ResultSetMetaData` class.

```
ResultSet rs;

// more code

ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int size=rsmd.getPrecision(COLUMN_INDEX);
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getPrecision(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getPrecision%28int%29)

Comment: So my column is a nvarchar and I got back a precision of 2147483647.  I would expect to get back something like 30 or something like that.  How do I determine the length of characters given the precision above?

Comment: @Andy well, i have't worked with `nvarchar` so i'm ot quite sure about it. But while i was reading, i got through followig links
http://www.hitachi.co.jp/Prod/comp/soft1/manual/hirdben/v9/d645610e/W4560470.HTM
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503715/jtds-incorrectly-reports-data-type-info-in-result-set-metadata-for-date-columns
the first links says that it should return `2*n`.
`msdn` site states that i can store 2gb of data and i think this is what you are getting and you are getting the maximum value. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the size using the sp_columns stored proc

e.g

```
exec sp_columns @table_name =  'MyTable', @column_name = 'MyColumn'
```

There's a few others including querying the information_schema as well.

Comment: is this method is specific to SQL-server or it it works on other databases as well?

Comment: sql server, but most dbms have have metatables accessed in various way, systables, sysobjects syscolumns etc. MySql's Describe. sp_columns is a nice api instead of doing a join on sysobjects and syscolumns.